# How can I fix pip Installer Proxy Error 11001

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, pip

I recently purged all the python files from my PC and installed 3.9.1 but am unable to pip install anything. After googling this error, the consensus is that the problem is due to a proxy. I am using my home internet and have no proxy. I checked my windows "Proxy Settings" and every has been disabled. I would appreciate any help in getting this solved.

```
pip install --user pandas

WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x000001EB96511730>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed'))': /simple/pandas/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x000001EB96511580>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed'))': /simple/pandas/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x000001EB96511610>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed'))': /simple/pandas/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x000001EB9652F130>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed'))': /simple/pandas/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x000001EB9652F2B0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed'))': /simple/pandas/
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pandas (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for pandas
```